# Which object points to use in OpenCV for cv2.stereoCalibrate?

Tags: opencv

For OpenCV 2.4, I have a set of object points and image points from both the left and right cameras. Is it acceptable to use either right or left object points for `cv2.stereoCalibrate`?

Comment: The object points should be the same for both cameras, since you are using those as reference points and they are visible by both cameras.

Comment: You're right, that resolves my question then. Thanks!